# (Python Google Colab) How to clean unwanted symbols and how to count most existing words in a text and output it

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, count, calculation

```
!pip install wikipedia
import re
import nltk
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
import wikipedia
wikipedia.set_lang("en")
a=wikipedia.page("bitcoin")
print(a.content)
a.content_frqunce = FreqDist(a.content)
a.content_count = len(a.content)
a.content_unique_count = len(set(a.content))
print(a.content)
print(a.content_unique_count)
print(a.content_count)
print(a.content_frqunce)
```

I wanna count the most existing words and I wanna write them in a list I mean I wanna output the top 10 most existing words in this text with the correct arrangement I also want to clean some symbols and blank spaces I hope I explain my problem clear and correct ^w^

Answer (score 0):

you can use counter from collections to get ordered data structure on frequency.

```
from collections import Counter
a = Counter(['a', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
print(a)
#Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 2, 'd': 1, 'c': 1})
```